# Removing title from content pane

Tags: views, panels

I have used a content pane in a panel to add a description on top of it. It was a success but I can't find a way to remove the pane title in the view. The screenshots are below:

[image]

I have also set the content pane title to none

[image]

There is no option in the panel for title.

So how can I remove it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can hide the title using CSS, for example with `style="display:none;"`.

Comment: Not the kind of exact formal solution I was looking for but, what the heck, it works. Thanks..

Answer (score 8):

In the view, there is an 'allow settings' link (bottom right of your screen shot). This allows you to select which settings can be changed within panels, including the title.

You can then, in panels, override the title with an empty string.

Comment: Contrary to what what Nikit said on Povylas's post, _this_ is the correct answer :)

Answer (score 6):

If I am not mistaken if you write `<No Title>` in the pane title field the pane title will not be displayed.

Comment: This is correct answer.

Comment: This is good for blocks, but not for pages, because you still want the actual window title. I think removing it through a tpl file is the best method, for me at least.

Answer (score 3):

In drupal 7, if we don't want to show title in Content Pane, then leave the **Title** field empty, even don't write `None` in the textfield, Just leave it empty.

Answer (score 1):

Module [Exclude Node Title](https://drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title):

Configure by content type and display mode from

- admin/config/content/exclude_node_title

Answer (score 0):

I use `<none>` in the title field. Seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement your panel through  `hook_default_page_manager_pages`or `hook_default_page_manager_handlers` you can add this code:

```
    $pane->configuration = array(
      'override_title' => 1,
      'override_title_text' => '',
      'override_title_heading' => 'h2',
    );
```